# Определение списка исполнителей и задач для системы

Tags: проектирование

Мне нужно определить список задач и исполнителей для системы создания модульных программ.
Думаю, что это только программист, который будет создавать на основе данной системы определенное модульное приложение. А основные его задачи: создает модули, создает кнопки, создает меню с кнопками, создает модальные окна, создает не модальные окна, создание таблицы с данными. Что вы можете посоветовать?

Comment: я вас щас удивлю - бывают (да что  там  - их множество если не большинство) модульные программы без кнопок меню и окон.

Comment: уточню, для создания desktop приложений

Comment: О господи. Создание кнопок и создание модулей в одном ряду, это круто.

Вам нужны программисты на модельные классы (возможно, многочисленные), программисты на бизнес-логику, и команда на UI.

Comment: еще нужен ОТК!